# How to measure a distance on a PDF

Tags: pdf

Is there a free plug-in for Adobe Reader to measure a distance on a PDF?

Is there another free reader out there that has this?

Answer (score 12):

Adobe reader itself has a measure feature under "tools/measure":

> The measuring tools are especially useful when you need to know the
>   distances or areas associated with objects in a form or computer-aided
>   design (CAD) drawing... The measuring tools are available to Reader
>   users only if the PDF creator enables measuring functionality.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Reader/8.0/help.html?content=WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7f91.html

As of this writing, the Linux version of Acrobat Reader is missing the tool.
Foxit is another alternative which includes a measure tool.

Comment: "The measuring tools are available to Reader users only if the PDF creator enables measuring functionality." -> Does it means we need Adobe Acrobat Pro to create the PDF?

Comment: @Yud: Nope. Many vector-drawing programs will export measure-ready files. Adobe Illustrator or InDesign, for example. You can measure any file as far as I can tell, but vector drawings will snap the ruler to the edges of bounding boxes/strokes.

Answer (score 8):

I am using the free [PDF-XChange](https://pdf-xchange.eu/pdf-xchange-editor/) pdf viewer, and it comes with a measuring tool. Screenshot taken from the free version:

[image: PDF-XChange measuring tool]

Comment: One shortcoming of the tool is that I cannot find where you can change the measuring unit... it will only measure in millimeters ?

Comment: For me, it only measures inches, but displays them in meters. But better than nothing

Answer (score 3):

> **[Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/addons.htm) :**

check it out here http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/addons.htm it's free, so fast small (no more than 4Mo) and it has a lot of addons including Measure Tools tools.

> Includes a distance tool, a perimeter
>   tool, and an area tool that will help
>   you to measure distance, perimeter or
>   area on a PDF page and automatically
>   transform the results into real-world
>   values.

Comment: Looks like the measure tools are part of the Pro Pack.  It's free for a year.

Comment: a year is enough I guess :p

Comment: Looks like its baseline these days